# I updated a contributed module in error

Tags: updating

I updated Panels in Drupal 7, forgetting that I had customised it, panicked, deleted the updated module and replaced the correct one via ftp.
Now I can't run update.php as it says the website encountered an unexpected error.
Is my best option to re-install the updated panels, then delete properly it through the module interface or is there a better solution? My site is large with 6 sub domains.
There are no errors showing in the log files, and no errors showing when the error message is posted. The system log shows updates are up to date, and my database was restored to a point before the updates occurred, so were my sites default and sites all directories. I have emptied the cache on the site and on my browser. I'm at a total loss as I would be able to trace error messages myself

Comment: You need to post the actual error from your Drupal and/or webserver logs.

Comment: Database backup from before the update/downgrade? Flushed caches? Logs? Error messages?

Comment: Please learn the lesson: You don't update a large site in production without a database backup or version control. Always update locally first, flush cache, perform database updates, flush cache again, check if everything's running, and only then commit the code changes via Git, pull them on the live site, flush cache, perform database updates, flush cache again.

Comment: Thank you leymanx but the code had been backed up, and the database. Both have been restored but I still can't run the update script. Logs, error messages have been checked and cache flushed but the update script will not run

Comment: Did you already enable "All messages" at https://example.com/admin/config/development/logging? Maybe also try `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', TRUE); ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);` in your settings.php to make more of that error message.